# What sort of [operation] is this?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operation) tag is too vague and ambigous. And it is tagged with all sorts of question. It hasn't got a wiki or an excerpt too!

So, are you people with me for **[operation-burnination]**?

Comment: There are lots of [tag:operation]-related tags, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsoperation+or+operation+or+afhttprequestoperation+or+nsinvocationoperation+or+afjsonrequestoperation+or+nsblockoperation+or+globalcompositeoperation+or+nsprintoperation+or+shfileoperation+or+unsupportedoperation+or+iasyncoperation+or+operations+or+operationcontract+or+operationcontext+or+operations-research+or+operation-aborted+or+operational-transform+or+operationalerror+or+operational+or+operation-contract

Comment: It was used as a combining word.  Most popular are [math-operation], [string-operation], [matrix-operation].  Tags that don't exist so the questioner couldn't do anything but use [math] [operation], etc.  If you don't create the dashed tag then it will just keep coming back.

Comment: There is also [tag:operations] which should probably be included in this proposed burnination. There are also only [35 "math operation(s)" questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math+operation+OR+math+operations), but I do get your point about re-tagging if it is burninated.